# Flattening Express data to JSON string in Labview

Tags: json, labview, nidaqmx, json-flattener

I am working on Labview. I want to flatten the Express data type coming out from my DAQ-Assistent into JSON string. I am using JKI JSON but it is showing an error of unsupported data type: Expressdata. Are there any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JSON VI does not know how to interpret the data from the express VI, it can't convert it into JSON. For example, the LabVIEWs native JSON VIs can not de/encode timestamps, since JSON does not have a timestamp data type. An additional convention on how to store timestamps would be necessary, such as seconds since 1970 or a string in ISO time format.

It is even possible that the data wire just contains some references, and storing the reference gives you nothing.

If you convert the express data to a more basic datatype like waveform, the JSON VI should be able to encode it.

Comment: Instructions for converting express type to waveform: https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/eecs20/labs/LabVIEW_Tutorials_PDF/HowtoUsetheConverttoandfromDynamicDataTutorial.pdf